# Iteration of ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I was reading about `ConcurrentHashMap`.

I read that it provides an Iterator that requires no synchronization and even allows the Map to be modified during iteration and thus there will be no `ConcurrentModificationException`.

I was wondering if this is a good thing as I might not get the element, put into `ConcurrentHashMap` earlier, during iteration as another thread might have changed it.

Is my thinking correct? If yes, is it good or bad?

Comment: I feel this is very valid question and not answered properly. example two threads with its own iterators on the same API; are running with a concurrent collection; and has to remove one of the element and should notify a client. If its removal not immediately reflect on the other itreator then TWO notification will be received by the client for single removal of that collections.

Answer (score 4):

> I was wondering if this is a good thing as I might not get the element, put into ConcurrentHashMap earlier, during iteration as another thread might have changed it.

I don't think this should be a concern - the same statement is true if you use synchronization and the thread doing the iteration happens to grab the lock and execute it's loop prior to the thread that would insert the value.

If you need some sort of coordination between your threads to ensure that some action takes place after (and only after) another action, then you still need to manage this coordination, regardless of the type of Map used.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the `ConcurrentHashMap` weakly consistent iterator is sufficient.  If instead you want a strongly consistent iterator, then you have a couple of options:

1. The [ctrie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctrie) is a hash array mapped trie that provides constant time snapshots. There is [Java source code](https://github.com/romix/java-concurrent-hash-trie-map/) available for the data structure.
2. Clojure has a [PersistentHashMap](http://code.google.com/p/clojure/source/browse/trunk/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentHashMap.java?r=1089) that you can use - this lets you iterate over a snapshot of the data.
3. Use a local database, e.g. [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) to store the data instead of using a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Use a composite primary key of key|timestamp, and when you "update" a value you instead store a new entry with the current timestamp. To get an iterator, retrieve a resultset with a `where timetamp < System.currentTimeMillis()` clause, and iterate over the resultset.

In either case you're iterating over a snapshot, so you've got a strongly consistent iterator; in the former case you run the risk of running out of memory, while the latter case is a more complex solution.

Comment: we are dealing in Java so please don't use other programming language like Clojure

Comment: @Anand Clojure is written in Java - you can use Clojure data structures in Java

Comment: @Anand I came across the [ctrie data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctrie) that looks to be a good match for what you're after. There is [Java source code](https://github.com/romix/java-concurrent-hash-trie-map/) available for the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of *concurrent* -anything is that you acknowledge concurrent activity, and don't trust that all access is serialized. With most collections, you cannot expect inter-element consistency without working for it.

If you don't care about seeing the latest data, but want a consistent (but possibly old) view of data, have a look at purely functional structures like [Finger Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree).